# Find a complex number that satisfies both $|z-3+i|=3$ and $|z+2-i|=|z-3+2i|$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, locus

What I did:

Let $z=x+yi$, Then:

$$|(x-3)+(y+1)i|=3$$
$$|(x+2)+(y-1)i|=|(x-3)+(y+2)i|$$

Since $|x+iy|=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$:

$$(x-3)^2+(y+1)^2=9$$
$$y=\frac{5x-4}{3}$$ Hence:

$$(x-3)^2+\bigg(\frac{5x-1}{3}\bigg)^2=9$$
Or
$$34x^2-64x+1=0$$
So
$$x_{1,2}=\frac{32\pm3\sqrt{110}}{34}$$
And

$$y_{1,2}=\frac{8\pm5\sqrt{110}}{34}$$
Hence

$$z_1=\frac{32+3\sqrt{110}}{34}+\frac{8+5\sqrt{110}}{34}i$$
$$z_2=\frac{32-3\sqrt{110}}{34}+\frac{8-5\sqrt{110}}{34}i$$
But, when I looked up the answer in the book:
[image]

I think there is a misprint in the book as this is the question:
[image]

I think that in part c they meant $|z+2-i|=|z-1+2i|$ and not $|z+2-i|=|z-3+2i|$, becuase then the answer would make sense, but I thought I would double check. Thanks for any help

Comment: I haven't read the question carefully, so won't try an answer. I do have a suggestion. Before you play with the algebra, think about the geometry. This is the intersection of a line and a circle. Draw the picture.

Answer (score 1):

Geometrically u are looking for the intersection of the circle centered at $(3,-1)$ with radius 3 and the perpendicular bisector of the line segment ralating the points $(-2,1)$ and $(3,-2)$

Comment: you forgot "and radius 3" :)